# Is there any way to write this query without using WITH Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Screenshot of table `account`:

[[image]]

Screenshot of table `trandetails`:

[[image]

Problem: Write a query to display  the total number of  withdrawals and total number of deposits being done by customer whose registration is C00001. Give the count an alias name of Trans_Count. 

I want to reduce line of code for the above question
I have written this query

Code:

```
with t as
(
select acnumber,transaction_type,count(transaction_type) as trans_type 
from trandetails as t
group by transaction_type,acnumber
)
,c as
(
select c.custid,c.acnumber
from account as c
where custid like 'C00001'
)
select c.custid,t.transaction_type,t.trans_type
from t inner join c on c.acnumber = t.acnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.custid,
       t.transaction_type,
       t.trans_type
FROM account AS c
     INNER JOIN( 
                 SELECT acnumber,
                        transaction_type,
                        COUNT(transaction_type) AS trans_type
                 FROM trandetails
                 GROUP BY transaction_type,
                          acnumber ) t ON c.acnumber = t.acnumber
WHERE c.custid LIKE 'C00001';
```

If acnumber is unique in account, then it would be further simpler:

```
SELECT c.custid,
       t.transaction_type,
       COUNT(t.transaction_type) AS trans_type
FROM account AS c
     INNER JOIN trandetails AS t ON c.acnumber = t.acnumber
WHERE c.custid LIKE 'C00001'
GROUP BY c.custid,
         t.transaction_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT c.custid, t.transaction_type, t.trans_type
FROM (SELECT acnumber, transaction_type, COUNT(transaction_type) AS trans_type 
      FROM trandetails
      GROUP BY transaction_type, acnumber
) t
INNER JOIN (SELECT custid, acnumber
            FROM account
            WHERE custid LIKE 'C00001'
) c
ON c.acnumber = t.acnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use subquery insted of CTE

```
select c.custid,
       t.transaction_type,
       t.trans_type
from account c
     inner join (
      select s.acnumber,
             s.transaction_type,
             count(s.transaction_type) as trans_type
      from trandetails as s
      group by s.transaction_type,
               s.acnumber) t on c.acnumber = t.acnumber
where c.custid = 'C00001'
```

Probably you have to use either `s.custid = 'C00001'` or something like that `s.custid like '%C00001%'`. `like` is used to search inside of some string, not for direct comparision for equality.

Answer (score 0):

See if that is what you want:

```
select a.custid
      ,t.transaction_type
      ,sum(t.transaction_amount) amount
from account a
    ,trandetails t
where t.acnumber = a.acnumber
  and a.custid = 'C00001'
group by a.custid
     ,t.transaction_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with conditional aggregation:

```
select a.custid,
       sum(case when d.transaction_type = 'Deposit' then 1 end) as DepositCount,
       sum(case when d.transaction_type = 'Withdrawal' then 1 end) as WithdrawalCount,
from account a
join trandetails d on a.acnumber = d.acnumber
where a.custid = 'C00001'
group by a.custid
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1: Avoid subquery if possible

Tip 2: Do not use LIKE clause if not required - in your case seems that '=' will do the job - here is a small testing sample:

```
DECLARE @account TABLE (
    custid VARCHAR(20),
    acnumber VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @trandetails TABLE (
    acnumber VARCHAR(20),
    transaction_type VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO
    @account
VALUES
    ('C00001', 'A00001'),
    ('C00002', 'A00002')

INSERT INTO
    @trandetails
VALUES
    ('A00001', 'Withdrawal'),
    ('A00001', 'Deposit'),
    ('A00002', 'Deposit')

SELECT
    acc.custid,
    td.transaction_type,
    count(td.transaction_type) AS trans_cnt
FROM
    @account acc
    INNER JOIN @trandetails td
        ON acc.acnumber = td.acnumber
WHERE
    acc.custid = 'C00001'
GROUP BY
    acc.custid,
    td.acnumber,
    td.transaction_type
```

Comment: 1) Because you could get a much worse execution plan especially on older SQL server versions and 2) because it makes sense to use the appropriate operations of you want to employ the optimal algorithm for retrieving your data from the hard drive :)

Comment: 1) Surely this is a little generalised as much would depend on indexing & the OP stated the version they were using, so is this relevent to SQL 2008? 2) Can you provide a link that shows `=` is optimal to `LIKE` for the example predicate?

Comment: I am losing the point of this discussion (and an off-topic in fact) - if I were you I would experiment and check the comparison function in the actual execution plans in 2008. Whatever, I would usually prefer the comparison that is aimed for the purpose ... and I didn't say it is a must ...

Comment: The point is that you have made statements and provided no evidence or explanation to support them. I wanted further information on why you made the statements you did so that I could improve my own scripting and , if challenged, have documentary evidence to back up my decisions, if based on your statements.